# Is there a mechanic for Passive Deception?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, social-combat, social-stats

Right now I have a situation with a Doppleganger has infiltrated a small section of the group.  It is passing itself off with the intentions of appearing to be someone important to one person and keeping that person alive so it can keep taking surface thoughts.

The question, I'd rather not have to roll Deception anytime something comes up or to tip my hand a bit if there is an Insight check.  I know we have Passive Perception, but I was wondering if the creature could have Passive Deception as well?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you review the linked question and see if it answers your question?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the underlying question here is something like "How do I handle a continuous ongoing deception without constantly rolling checks?" which is an interesting question that's not a dupe of the linked question. It might make sense to create a new question asking that more directly.